# Using Struct in C to create a library for items and giving location feedback based upon user entry. I just cant seem to find my error

Tags: c, struct, structure

```
//make a location marker for key items

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct find {int index; char name[50]; char location[50]; };

int main() {
    
    char locate_item[50];

//using struct to add items 

    struct find item1;
    item1.index = 1;
    strcpy(item1.name, "guitar");
    strcpy(item1.location, "Usually near the table in the living room area.\n");
        
    struct find item2;
    item2.index = 2;
    strcpy(item2.name, "ipad");
    strcpy(item2.location, "Usually on the table or charging on the bed.\n");

    //using while and if statements to get user feedback and display the appropriate location
    
    while (locate_item != item1.name || locate_item != item2.name) {
        
        printf("what is the item you want to find? \n");
        scanf("%s", locate_item);
        printf("You entered %s\n", locate_item);
        
        if (locate_item == item1.name) {
            printf("%s", item1.location);
        } else if (locate_item == item2.name) {
            printf("%s", item2.location);
        } else {
            printf("Incorrect entry. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This is the compiled message I get for my code.......                      
what is the item you want to find?      
guitar             
You entered guitar    
Incorrect entry. Please try again.    
what is the item you want to find?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to **[edit]** your questions to improve them.

Comment: It doesn't show any error messages but I still cant understand the problem. Please Help

Comment: And you seem to have missed something very basic in your text-book, or skipped a class, because comparing strings can't be done with `==` (or `!=`).

Comment: Also you can't use uninitialized variables. Their values will be *indeterminate* (look at them as garbage), and using an uninitialized arrays as a string can often lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I am new to the game and learning C from youtube videos. Your help means a lot to me.

Comment: Also would you please point out the location of error from your second feedback.

Comment: Youtube videos to learn programming seams to be a hit and miss, and mostly miss. Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and if possible take some classes.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`locate_item != item1.name || locate_item != item2.name` compares pointer, however, you want to use `strcmp()` to compare two strings by value.  `strcmp()` returns 0 if the two strings are the same.

In either case, your program doesn't make a lot of sense.  You probably want to find `locate_item` in the an array of `items` (renamed from `find`) along these lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct item {
    int index;
    char name[50];
    char location[50];
};

int main() {
    struct item items[] = {
        { 1, "guitar", "Usually near the table in the living room area." },
        { 2, "ipad", "Usually on the table or charging on the bed." },
        { 0 }
    };
    for(;;) {
        printf("what is the item you want to find? \n");
        char locate_item[50];
        scanf("%s", locate_item);
        //printf("You entered %s\n", locate_item);
        for(int i = 0; items[i].name[0]; i++) {
            if(!strcmp(items[i].name, locate_item)) {
                printf("%s\n", items[i].location);
                goto done;
            }
        }
        printf("Incorrect entry. Please try again.\n");
    }
done:
    return 0;
}
```